# Jaming message in BlueoothChat program on android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am currently developing my program using sample BluetoothChat program on android device. This is the website that you can refer to: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/index.html

Base on some reasons, I want to continue sending the message to the receiver. Hence, I do this on a method called sendMessage() in BluetoothChat class.

```
byte[] send = message.getBytes(); 
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  //simply add a while loop here
mChatService.write(send);
```

Sometimes, the messages will jam to each other. e.g. the message is 1234. So the receiver should receive five indivual messages. However, the receiver may receive 4 message and one message is 12341234. The pattern is not unique. Sometimes the receiver 3 message with two message is 12341234. Sometimes it runs perfectly which receive five indivual messages.

I don't know which one(sender or receiver or both) having the problem. How to fix such problem? Thx a lot~

Comment: Post your code, and perhaps give an explanation of why you need to send it 5x in a row.  Also, check out the links (on the right) under **Related**.

Comment: Actually, I am not sending message but several file continually. It has some differences but the concept is same. The jamming problem is that the file header jam with file content sometimes(I send the header first, then the content, you can treat them as two continually messages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are assuming a one-one correspondence between write and reads.  Often it does work that way, but there is no guarantee - the odd behavior that you are seeing is actually typical.

As a result, you are responsible for breaking the data that you receive (via your socket.read) into messages.

Typically you would use messages of a fixed length or you would include the length of the message in the message header.  Using fixed length messages really simplifies things, but is usually not flexible enough.

Comment: I have try to include message length before, it doesn't work good. e.g. the message is abcd and two same mssages jammed. The received message will be {"message header" abcd "message header" abcd}.That means I have to deal with two messages at the same time and this makes things quite complicated. Is that any way to prevent the jamming problem?

Comment: Actually, I am not sending message but several file continually. So I can't have fixed length content. The jamming problem is that the file header jam with file content.

When I try it on debug mode and run my program one line by one line. No jamming problem occur. So I think adding delay counter between sneding file header and sending file content will work. But the jamming still occur when running in normal mode(I don't know my counter is long enough, but I have set it for quite long I think)

Comment: I've just re-read your question and I stand by my answer.  So, if you send some messages that are 4 bytes long (as in your example), and the receiving app receives 8 bytes, it must split that into two messages.  In order to do the splitting, the receiver has to know how long each message is.

Comment: Your solution is totally okay for my problem, but I am just looking for a way to make sure the data transmission is reliable(it just seems to admit bluetooth is not reliable and I have to split the message by myself). Because I am running out of time on changing my code...

Comment: I think that Bluetooth is unreliable - but that's another story.  This issue that we are discussing is not a problem with Bluetooth or with Android - it is normal behavior for sockets in my experience.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way around it - the code for reading from the socket is more complicated then for writing due to this issue.